# Can send but not receive emails on my new cpanel email account

Tags: email, smtp, cpanel, smtp-auth

I created an email account using cpanel, the problem is that I can't receive incoming emails to that account, here is the error message I get:

> The response from the remote server was: 550 Please turn on SMTP
>   Authentication in your mail client. mail-il1-f170.google.com
>   [209.85.166.170]:33099 is not permitted to relay through this server
>   without authentication.

But I can send emails using that same account, could somebody explain to me what's the problem or show we me way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: The problem is resolved: I needed to change the email routing settings in the cpanel dashboard to the appropriate ones,

Comment: Can you give me some advice on how you accomplished this?